# ZF2 - Why are Form Elements always marked true

Tags: php, zend-framework2

first: this is an architecture question. Please don't answer how to solve the technical problem, that's already done in several places, f.e.: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/2761

I don't seem to get it. Form Elements in ZF2 are not only marked required but this is also hardcoded.

Example \Zend\Form\Element\Select

```
    public function getInputSpecification()
{
    $spec = array(
        'name' => $this->getName(),
        'required' => true,
    );

    if ($validator = $this->getValidator()) {
        $spec['validators'] = array(
            $validator,
        );
    }

    return $spec;
}
```

I just cannot understand making this not optional. I want to use ZF2 Elements right out of the box, now i have to extend all elements i need to use.

Since in most our forms we have some optional elements this means we always need to use our own derived classes.

But that just seems wrong so i hope someone could help me out explaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're telling us to not answer in a technical fashion. Ultimately this means you want to argue about the defaults that are given out by ZF2. Argueably this makes it completely opinion based and therefore should be closed.

Now as user#somenumber told you, there is barely anything hardcoded in `Zend\Form`. It's all given defaults and quite frankly - yes, this is opinion based - the defaults in ZF2 are pretty awesome.

You don't need to overwrite the elements, you just have to overwrite the required-flag. Of course if you want a global default of required false then yes, you'll have to overwrite, but that is the beauty of ZF2. You can make everything the way you want.

The default of elements being required by default is a good thing. I'm pretty certain that more than 50% of all Form Elements found on the internet are required. Therefore setting required as default is a good decision.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and of course you are right, this is completely opinion based.

I also must apologize since i was really frustrated on the day i wrote this because a setting from ZF1 that needed about 5 Minutes was not there. And when something is missing i look for the answer why this has been abandoned.

ZF2 is really awesome so i wanted to understand the reason why required is not a flag anymore and i thought a long way where to ask the question since this is not a bug. There was a formulated reason for the decision and i wanted to learn it.

Comment: @Dready The separation comes from the principle "separatin of concerns". The attribute `required` on a `Form\Element` represents the HTML-Attribute required. When it comes to validation, you'll actually need to set this inside the validator. Yes, ZF2 requires a lot of "new" ways of thinking, but once understood, it is actually far more clear and intuitive.